# Significance of various graph types

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

There are a lot of [named graph types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_named_graphs). I am wondering what is the criteria behind this categorization. Are different types applicable in different context? Moreover, can a business application (from design and programming perspective) benefit anything out of these categorizations? Is this analogous to design patterns?

Comment: Hmm. There are probably a trillion trees on earth. Some of them are named and most of them not. Why? It is the same reason. Some of the graphs are historically and scientifically important and that is why they have "names"s.

Comment: The answer may be very different to programmers than to mathematicians. This might be in the wrong spot, depending on the context, but I can't be the only SOer hoping to learn something from this question!! :)

Comment: @ElKamina - Agree but how and why are the important isn't listed on wikipedia. Moreover, can a business application benefit anything out of these categorizations? Is this analogous to design patterns?

Comment: @ElKamina Your comment I think is out of place. OP is specifically asking if any of them are important to us. You can't just say "They're named because they're important" - you've essentially restarted his question!

Comment: I could see a benefit to recognizing named graphs if you could prove a non-descript input graph was [isomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism) to a named graph.

Comment: @corsiKa My point was, each of them are named for a reason. Just click through the wiki link at the bottom of each image to find out why and if it is useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've given names to common families of graphs for several reasons:

- **Certain families of graphs have nice, simple properties**.  For example, [trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) have numerous useful properties (there's exactly one path between any pair of nodes, they're maximally acyclic, they're minimally connected, etc.) that don't hold of arbitrary graphs.  [Directed acyclic graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) can be [topologically sorted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ordering), which normal graphs cannot.  If you can model a problem in terms of one of these types of graphs, you can use specialized algorithms on them to extract properties that can't necessarily be obtained from an arbitrary graph.
- **Certain algorithms run faster on certain types of graphs**.  Many NP-hard problems on graphs, which as of now don't have any polynomial-time algorithms, can be solved very easily on certain types of graphs.  For example, the [maximum independent set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29) (choose the largest collection of nodes where no two nodes are connected by an edge) is NP-hard, but can be solved in polynomial time for trees and [bipartite graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).  The 4-coloring problem (determine whether the nodes of a graph can be colored one of four different colors without assigning the same color to adjacent nodes) is NP-hard in general, but is immediately true for [planar graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) (this is the famous *four-color theorem*).
- **Certain algorithms are easier on certain types of graphs**.  A [matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in a graph is a collection of edges in the graph where no two edges share an endpoint.  Maximum matchings can be used to represent ways of pairing people up into groups.  In a bipartite graph, a maximum matching can be used to represent a way of assigning people to tasks such that no person is assigned two tasks and no task is assigned to two people.  There are many fast algorithms for finding maximum matchings in bipartite graphs that work quickly and are easy to understand.  The corresponding algorithms for general graphs are significantly more complicated and slightly less efficient.
- **Certain graphs are historically significant**.  Many named graphs are named after someone who used the graph to disprove a conjecture about properties of arbitrary graphs.  The [Petersen graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph), for example, is a counterexample to many theorems that seem true about graphs but are actually not.
- **Certain graphs are useful in theoretical computer science**.  An [expander graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph) is a graph where, intuitively, any collection of nodes must be connected to a proportionally larger collection of nodes in the graph.  Not all graphs are expander graphs.  Expander graphs are used in many results in theoretical computer science, such as one proof of the PCP theorem and in the proof that [SL = L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL_%28complexity%29).

This is not an exhaustive list of why we care about different graph families, but hopefully it helps motivate their usage and study.

Hope this helps!